# TailwindCSS 3.0 Upgrade overriding button styles

Tags: css, webpack, tailwind-css, dart-sass

### Problem:

Button class being overridden by default tailwind base classes. Not sure why my classes on the element aren't being applied.

### Question:

How can I get my styles to apply properly?

#### Screenshot:

[image: Chrome Tools displaying CSS issue]

As you can see background color on .documentCategory__row is being overridden by button, [type=button] on index.scss which is being defined within @tailwind/base.

```css
/* index.scss */
:root {
  --color-primary: #00a3e0;
  --color-secondary: #470a68;
  --color-success: #87d500;
  --color-accent: #e87722;

  /* Dark themes below */
  --color-dark-primary: rgba(31, 41, 55, 1);
  --dark-text: rgba(187, 193, 198, 1);
}

@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with me switching to dart-scss so here is my webpack configuration in case I am missing something

```
import path from 'path'
import { Configuration as WebpackConfiguration, HotModuleReplacementPlugin } from 'webpack'
import { Configuration as WebpackDevServerConfiguration } from 'webpack-dev-server';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin'
import ESLintPlugin from 'eslint-webpack-plugin'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

interface Configuration extends WebpackConfiguration {
  devServer?: WebpackDevServerConfiguration;
}

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 4000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader', // postcss loader needed for tailwindcss
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: '../fonts',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
    }),
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
      // relative path is from src
        { from: 'public/images', to: 'images' },
      ],
    }),
    // Add type checking on dev run
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
    }),

    // Add lint checking on dev run
    new ESLintPlugin({
      extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    }),
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};

export default config
```

If there are other files I am missing that are needed let me know!

Comment: Currently I just added !important to my class and that gets me a work around for now...

Comment: I am running into the same issue, but I'm not using dart-scss.

Comment: Similar issue reported in Tailwind's GitHub repo: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7049

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without seeing what your `index.tsx` looks like I can only make a guess, but here's what caused this issue in our app:

in our `index.tsx` we were importing `index.css` **after** importing our component tree with `import App from 'src/App`. thus the css was loaded into the site in the wrong order. imports from components first (css modules, normal css imports), tailwind last.

go to your entry file (probably `index.tsx`) and try moving your `import 'index.scss'` line above importing the root component.

like this for example

```
/* index.tsx */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css'; // this file holds all tailwind styles
import { App } from 'src/App';
// ...
```

read more here:

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7304#discussioncomment-2256226

Answer (score 1):

Even i faced the same issue but I am using `Vue3` + `element-ui-plus`, after spending more than 6 hours my solution is to set `:native-type='null'`:

`<el-button type='primary' round @click='handleClick' :native-type='null'>Click Me</el-button>`

but this is kinda "hack", this either need to be fixed by `Tailwind` or by `element-ui` team. Anyhow, for now enjoy ;)

And the discussion is on [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5969#discussioncomment-2980522)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue using tailwindcss v3 and NextUI, and button's background were "transparent". By adding type = {null}, to button's I solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

For `Vite` users: If you're getting transparent buttons while using `vite` with `tailwindcss` and `material-tailwind`:

- You need to wrap your tailwindcss config with the `WithMT` function
- You need to wrap your entire application with the `ThemeProvider` coming from @material-tailwind/react

Examples here:
https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/guide/vite